# Prove that these two sets are equal.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the following two sets are equal:

The interval $\left[a,b\right]$

The set $\left\lbrace y\in\mathbb{R}: \text{there exists } s,t\in\left[0,1\right] \text{ such that } s+t=1 \text{ and } y=sa+tb\right\rbrace$

I understand that the two sets are equal, since $s=1-t$.  This implies that if $t=0$, $y=a$, and if $t=1$, $y=b$.  But this is one of those problems where setting up a proof eludes me.

I suppose I have to do a two-direction proof since I am trying to prove the equivalence of two sets.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show inclusion in both directions. To show the second set is contained in the first is easier: if $y = sa + tb = sa + (1-s)b$, then $y \ge sa + (1-s)a = a$ since $b>a$, and also $y\le sb + (1-s)b = b$. The other direction: suppose $a\le x \le b$. Let $s = \frac{b-x}{b-a}$ and $t = 1-s$.

Comment: I understand the first part of your answer.  But for the second part, I don't see how s+t=1, which is a requirement of the set.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $t=1-s$. I've corrected the post.

Comment: Thanks, I see how to get the answer.  One question though, what was your line of thinking to come up with the expression for $s$ in the second part of your answer?

Comment: Think of the representation $x=sa + tb$ as the fraction $s$ of the way from $b$ to $a$ (so if $s=0$, then $x=b$; if $s=1$ then $x=a$). What must $s$ then be? Clearly what I wrote above.